# bootstrap 4 accordion not closing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, accordion

I am having problems with accordion. It displays ok. But when i open an accordion i want the other accordions to close automaticaly. I have no idea why this is wrong. below is my html and css. I have search a lot on google but could not find a good solution. I hope someone can help me to find what is wrong.

Thank you very much

```css
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f068";
  float: right;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  float: right !important;
  content: "\f067";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2972279885.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#shapes" aria-expanded="false">
                    Shapes
                </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="shapes" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
            <li>Line</li>
            <li>Circle</li>
            <li>Rectangle</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#basicshapes" aria-expanded="false">
                    Basic Shapes
                </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="basicshapes" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#components" aria-expanded="false">
                    Components
                </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="components" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
            <li>Station</li>
            <li>Zone</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`data-parent="#accordion"` should be on the `class="panel-collapse collapse"` div instead of the anchor.

```css
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f068";
  float: right;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  float: right !important;
  content: "\f067";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2972279885.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#shapes" aria-expanded="false">
                Shapes
            </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="shapes" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
            <li>Line</li>
            <li>Circle</li>
            <li>Rectangle</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#basicshapes" aria-expanded="false">
                Basic Shapes
            </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="basicshapes" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#components" aria-expanded="false">
                Components
            </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="components" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
            <li>Station</li>
            <li>Zone</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, this work great and no jquery script. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome :) Please accept this answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add Script like that

```
var $myGroup = $('#accordion');
   $myGroup.on('show.bs.collapse','.collapse', function() {
   $myGroup.find('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Hope it Works for you